# Mathematicians talking about their identity as a person and as a mathematician?

Tags: reference-request, philosophy, mathematicians

I was wondering if any of you know of any books, articles, interviews, youtube videos, ... (etc) where a mathematician talks about his or her identity as a person and as a mathematician? Thank you for any sources!

Comment: Have you looked at Marge Murray's book Women Becoming Mathematicians, MIT Press?

Comment: There's a book, Mathematical People, and a sequel, More Mathematical People.

Comment: Ulam, Stanislaw (1983). Adventures of a Mathematician

Comment: At first I was expecting a pun with regards to the meaning of "identity" in the context of group theory.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by someone talking about their "identity".  Most of the examples below are autobiographies, where the authors talk about their lives and experiences.  Is that what you are looking for, or something more metaphysical?

Comment: @NateEldredge, i think i am interested in their life stories and experiences. As a student struggling to find how mathematics fits into his personal identity, I'm wondering at what point a mathematician might feel comfortable identifying him/herself as a "mathematician," whatever that may mean to him/her.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A mathematician's apology. G.H.Hardy

Comment: The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Mathematician's_Apology) gives an overview, and [the Google Books reviews](http://books.google.com/books/about/A_Mathematician_s_Apology.html?id=beImvXUGD-MC) may also be helpful.

Comment: You can get the book online I suppose.

Comment: You can buy the e-book for Amazon's Kindle, but the Wikipedia article gives a link to a version that is public domain in Canada.

Comment: While that's a good book, he is pretty unrepresentative of what mathematicians are like. Not necessarily a reason not to read it, of course.

Answer (score 9):

Walter Rudin wrote a wonderful [autobiography](http://books.google.com/books/about/The_Way_I_Remember_It.html?id=f0fgS00yZY4C) that does a nice job of balancing between talking about his personal life and his mathematical pursuits.  Best of all, it reads like Rudin :)

Answer (score 8):

Here are some for consideration.

- [*Russell*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Philosophical_Development)
- [*Newman*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_R._Newman)
- [*Hardy*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Mathematician%27s_Apology)

I think it is unusual to write a biography about yourself. Let me qualify this. If you consider the ratio of mathematicians to ones that wrote about themselves, I think the ratio is very low. I have no statistics to prove that.

If you look at 'a' list of the [*'100' top mathematicians*](http://fabpedigree.com/james/mathmen.htm), which is highly debatable, how many do you suppose self published? Next question, how many have had biographies written about them? 
If you look at this list of [*mathematician biographaphical info*](http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/BiogIndex.html), you get an idea of how many there are to choose from. The same question can be asked of the greatest physicists.

There are many biographies about mathematicians written by others like Nash, Erdos, ...

Comment: Andre Weil wrote an autobiography.

Comment: Halmos wrote an "automathography."  Wiener wrote an autobiography "I am a Mathematician."

Comment: While not a full-fledged autobiography, Jean Dieudonne's [Mathematics -- The Music of Reason](http://www.amazon.com/dp/038753346X/ref=rdr_ext_tmb) devotes the first chapter to taking readers "on a little trip to the unknown country of mathematicians" before trying to describe the broad sweep of modern mathematical history.

Comment: Halmos and Wiener, mentioned by @Trurl, fit the bill of "a mathematician talk[ing] about his or her identity as a person and as a mathematician" (and both make for a truly fascinating read). Laurent Schwartz, *Un mathématicien aux prises avec le siècle*, Paris, O. Jacob, 1997, is another one.

Comment: If you consider the ratio of people to ones that wrote about themselves, is it lower or higher than that for mathematicians?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: I was wondering that too. Certainly, there are a lot of Hollywood types that have written about themselves, but that might be a function of narcissism. I was wondering if there are more physicists that have written about themselves than mathematicians and I think the numbers are comparable. This is probably also true about biographies of all the famous ones, but I am only guessing. Regards

Comment: narcissism: hit it right on the head (at least with respect to the Hollywood types!). Those with something truly worth saying are often too humble (and too honorable) to "put it all out there."

Answer (score 6):

It might not fit the bill perfectly, but "Surely you're joking, Mr. Feynman," is about both Feynman's exploits as a physicist and as a general goof-ball.  I wouldn't say it's a deep book, compared to say Hardy's "Apology," but it's a good read and offers a bit of insight into his way of thinking about problems.

Comment: I think it actually is a deep book -- because of the way it teaches, by example, how to think like a scientist.  Feynman's way of thinking is contagious.

Answer (score 6):

A selection :

- Stanislaw Ulam ['Adventures of a Mathematician'](http://books.google.com/books?id=U2_zEZOHdU4C&printsec=frontcover) should not be missed (MJD had it in his comments too)
- ['Littlewood's miscellany'](http://books.google.com/books?id=MjVgeT7Laf8C&printsec=frontcover) (anecdotes)
- Laurent Schwartz ['Un mathématicien aux prises avec le siècle'](http://books.google.com/books?id=Eqc0cyFR0AEC&printsec=frontcover#v=o) translated as ['A Mathematician Grappling With His Century'](http://books.google.com/books?id=xVrC7ek7iRwC&printsec=frontcover)
- Feynman's ['Surely you're joking, Mr. Feynman'](http://books.google.com/books?id=7papZR4oVssC&printsec=frontcover) and I found his book deep ! :-) A physicist of course but he could have been a mathematician if not for insisting for Mathematics to be 'useful'.
- Andreï Sakharov's ['Memoirs'](http://books.google.com/books?id=ICIhAQAAMAAJ) (he had to rewrite his book three times because it was stolen probably by KGB!). He was a physicist too and an humanist and another point of view is always useful.

Answer (score 4):

The map of my life, Goro Shimura. And of course the stuff by Grothendieck

Answer (score 3):

There is also Steven Strogatz "[The Calculus of Friendship](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691150389)" although not very detailed and extensive but a very nice short easy to read mixture of his personal life and some math.

Answer (score 1):

Consider looking for non-book sources. Mathematicians have also written essays, given interviews, and in general done things that give them a glimpse into the non-mathematical sides of their thinking. For example, Doron Zeilberger has interesting opinions on his website (be aware that his writing is often tongue-in-cheek). C. P. Snow's essay *The Two Cultures* is essential reading. And there are others.

Often you'll find great articles in the *Notices of the AMS* or such publications about specific mathematicians. Sometimes they are tributes to the recently deceased, and many mathematicians who knew them personally weigh in and share stories. Obituary tributes can also be found on personal blogs here and there.

Of course, a mathematician need not be deceased to have a good article written about them. I liked a recent one in the *Notices* about John H. Conway of free will theorem fame. The article included an interview and was a pleasure to read. If you're looking for interviews, the *Notices* are probably a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

"Théorème vivant" by Cédric Villani (2012) if you read french, or if traduced yet. 
May be what you are looking for, by a mathematician at mid-career.