# Books about maths (or science in general) and emotions

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

I was wondering if there are any books that combine and talk about math (or science in general) and emotions such as Steve Strogatz's book, The Calculus of Friendship?

Related but not so related (as they are not necessarily about science and emotions) that come to my mind are the ones mentioned in the answers [**here**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/443156/mathematicians-talking-about-their-identity-as-a-person-and-as-a-mathematician).

I do realise that this is a somewhat ill-posed question, so please do suggest edits to make this question more precise and relevant.

Comment: [The Mathematics of Love](https://www.amazon.com/Mathematics-Love-Patterns-Ultimate-Equation/dp/1476784884) by Hannah Fry? But this is *very* popular.

Comment: @ChubbyChef Although I have not read this book isn't it about looking at dating through lens of mathematics (e.g. how many dates till you find your partner, etc.)? I am referring to emotional stories/arc combined with math and that could also mean talking about, say the interesting life of Grothendieck or the journey of Strogatz and his teacher through their correspondences.

Comment: Oh, I see. Then my favourite has got to be [Logicomix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logicomix) - beware though, it's a graphic novel and not always historically accurate.

Comment: Oh, I have read that. I love it! Any other suggestions?